# Jquery based button slider

Tags: jquery, slider, css-animations

I am creating my first jquery function.  There is a set of buttons above a view window.  The view window initializes with a div, when one of the buttons is pressed the corresponding div slides into the view window.

It works semi ok in firefox (doesnt work in any other browser) but eventually no div slides into the view window.  I believe the issue has to do with the css left values going out of the range, but i am unsure how to fix it.

**js**

```
$(function() {
var prevButton = 3;
$("#par3").show();

$(".window_control").click(function() {
    var cur = this.id;

    if(cur != prevButton){

        var activeItem = $("#par"+prevButton);
        var nextItem = $('#par'+cur);

        var slider = $(".slider");
        var finalWidth = slider.width()*2;
        var animationTime = 2000;

        var cssDir = (prevButton > cur) ? "right" : "left";
        var animation = (prevButton > cur) ? { left: '+=' + finalWidth } : { left: '-=' + finalWidth };

        prevButton = cur;

        activeItem
            .animate(animation, animationTime);

        nextItem
            .show()
            .css(cssDir, finalWidth)
            .animate(animation, animationTime);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you're not using the native:

```
 $('div').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Comment: the reason is because i could not figure out how to set a delay so the user cannot click another button and have the slide play over another.

Comment: Your answer did help, i just realized this method can also have a complete function.  Thanks bud.  The other reason i went with animate is the gap i can set between the current and next div, but im sure i can figure it out.  Thanks again for the help.